# json.decode() Unexpected end of input (at character 1)

Tags: http, post, flutter

I am facing a anonymus closure error in flutter while signing in a user. It worked a few days before but now its not working, I dont no why. So please help and thanks in advance..Whenever i fill the details and tap on the signin button it throws the below error---

```
E/flutter ( 2914): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 2914): FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)
E/flutter ( 2914): 
E/flutter ( 2914): ^
E/flutter ( 2914): 
E/flutter ( 2914): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert/runtime/libconvert_patch.dart:1358:5)
E/flutter ( 2914): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.close (dart:convert/runtime/libconvert_patch.dart:511:7)
E/flutter ( 2914): #2      _parseJson (dart:convert/runtime/libconvert_patch.dart:30:10)
E/flutter ( 2914): #3      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:540:36)
E/flutter ( 2914): #4      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:167:41)
E/flutter ( 2914): #5      _SignInState._login.<anonymous closure> (package:restaurant_app/signin.dart:81:23)
```

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:restaurant_app/globalVar.dart';
import 'package:restaurant_app/homescreen.dart';
 import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
 import 'package:restaurant_app/signup.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter_html_view/html_parser.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin 
{
TabController controller;
TextEditingController _email = new TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _password = new TextEditingController();
bool loading;

 final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> 
();

@override
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
controller = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
loading = false;
_email = new TextEditingController(text: "rajeshvishnani");
_password = new TextEditingController(text: "Rajesh@MaaKiRasoi");
}

@override
void dispose() {
// TODO: implement dispose
super.dispose();
controller.dispose();
setState(() {
  loading = false;
});
_email.dispose();
_password.dispose();
}

final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
bool _autoValidate = false;

Future _writer(String username, String password, String token) async {
final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
await storage.write(key: authTokenKeys, value: token);
print(await storage.read(key: authTokenKeys));
await storage.write(key: nameKeys, value: username);
print(await storage.read(key: nameKeys));
await storage.write(key: passwordKeys, value: password);
}

  static final String authTokenKeys = 'auth_token';
static final String nameKeys = 'username';
static final String passwordKeys = 'password';

_login(username, password) async {
setState(() {
  loading = true;
});

var body = json.encode({
  "username": username,
  "password": password,
});

Map<String, String> headers = {
  'Content-type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
};

await http
    .post("${GlobalVar.Ip}/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token",
        body: body, headers: headers)
    .then((response) {
  var body = json.decode(response.body);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // TODO: you need to store body['token'] to use in some authentication
    loading = false;
    _writer(_email.text, _password.text, body['token']);
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext ctx) => HomePage()));
  } else {
    // TODO: alert message
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(body['message']),
    );
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
  setState(() {
    loading = false;
  });
  });
}

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
  body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('images/art.png'),
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
            Colors.white12.withOpacity(0.2), BlendMode.dstATop),
      ),
    ),
    child: ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 30,
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            radius: 55.0,
            backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/logo.png'),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 30,
        ),
        Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 300,
              child: new Center(
                child: new Container(
                  height: 10.0,
                  color: Colors.black12,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
                ),
                Chip(
                  label: Text(
                    "SIGN IN",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: Color(0xFFD1A155),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 35,
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 12,
                    height: 2.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                Chip(
                  label: Text(
                    "SIGN UP",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 35,
        ),
        Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              "Welcome back!",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                color: Color(0xFFD1A155),
              ),
            )),
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 30,
        ),
        Form(
          key: _formKey,
          autovalidate: _autoValidate,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Theme(
                data: ThemeData(
                  hintColor: Colors.black26,
                  primaryColor: Color(0xFFD1A155),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    //validator: _email.text.isEmpty?:null,
                    controller: _email,

                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border:
                            OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide()),
                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.email,
                          color: Color(0xFFD1A155),
                        ),
                        hintText: 'Email Address',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 45,
              ),
              Theme(
                data: ThemeData(
                    primaryColor: Color(0xFFD1A155),
                    hintColor: Colors.black26),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    obscureText: true,
                    controller: _password,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border:
                            OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide()),
                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.lock,
                          color: Color(0xFFD1A155),
                        ),
                        hintText: 'Password',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0, left: 10.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ActionChip(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          avatar: Checkbox(
                            value: false,
                            onChanged: (bool z) {
                              print(z);
                            },
                            activeColor: Color(0xFFD1A155),
                          ),
                          label: Text("Remember Me"),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Forgot Password?",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFFD1A155),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    _login(_email.text, _password.text);
         //                        Navigator.push(
        //                            context,
    //                            MaterialPageRoute(
     //                                builder: (context) => HomePage()));
                  },
                  child: loading
                      ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                      : Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 13,
                          //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.8,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFFD1A155),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "LOGIN",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 15,
        ),
        Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 2.0,
              child: new Center(
                child: new Container(
                  height: 10.0,
                  color: Colors.black12,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 18,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 11,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(23.0),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black12)),
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                "OR",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
              )),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 30,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 13,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.2,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black12)),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 18.0,
                    ),
                    Icon(Icons.tag_faces),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Facebook",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0, color: Colors.blue),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 40,
              ),
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 13,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.3,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black12)),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 18.0,
                    ),
                    Icon(Icons.tag_faces),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Google+",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0, color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 20,
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUp())),
            child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                    text: "Don't have an account?",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black87),
                    children: <TextSpan>[
                  TextSpan(
                      text: ' Sign up',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFFD1A155),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ])),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 30,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: "anonymous closure" is the least relevant part of the error. `response.body` - the value you pass to `json.decode(...)` is not valid JSON. Already the first character is invalid - probably it's just `null`.

Comment: The "anonymous closure" comes from `then(...)` where you pass an anonymous closure that calls `json.decode()` and is shown as first stack frame in the exception output. Because the passed closure (or function) does not have a name like for example `_login` it is listed as "anonymous closure".

Comment: Then what should I do to solve the error?

Comment: Figure out what value you get from `response.body`

Comment: I tried to print response.body but nothing came...

Comment: what do you mean by "nothing came"? before `var body = json.decode(response.body);` call `print('body: [${response.body}]');`

Comment: Perhaps it's an empty string `""`

Comment: @Bishal Das, how did you fix your problem? I'm facing same one... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55367268/formatexception-unexpected-end-of-input-at-character-1

Comment: I think there is a syntax error in your JSON, use jsonlint.com to check for syntax errors.

Comment: i get this error even though the app runs fine without issue. Its like theres a delay in reading the results or something

Answer (score 29):

I also have similar type of error, Be make sure that the argument of `.decode` method shouldn't be empty object. Instead of using this line:

```
var body = json.decode(response.body);
```

Try

```
if(response.body.isNotEmpty) {
    json.decode(response.body);
}
```

Do try this, hope it will work for you.

Comment: This helped me in debugging, my problem was in the backend, the response was wrong, it was fixed there and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Print your body and double check you aren't trying to decode an array rather than on object.

Comment: This! Second time I am getting caught out by this. I have a query that returns a single object and I was treating it like an array.

Answer (score 1):

check your backend it return null object in the response body

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this error by adding `.trim()`

```
     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final responseBody = response.body.trim(); 
       if (responseBody.isNotEmpty) {
       } else {};
```

When using `jsonDecode` or `json.decode`, it expects a valid JSON response even if it's an empty json object or array. The .trim() function removes any blank response from your API and convert it to an empty json data.

Lets say you are sending an `http request` to `Create`, `Update` or `Delete` data from your database but your API does not return any jsonData value such as `echo json_encode("Successful");`

This was my case. The decode function treated the response as a not-valid json response. You either need to trim it and decode only if the response is not empty, or modify your API to send some kind of response no matter what operation it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar type of problem, i tried everything but eventually the problem was that I was using http intead of using https even though the apis was in https, i forgot to add s at in http.
After changing to https from http the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your header in http or dio in flutter

```
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check You Header If you are Sending Jwt Token

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue because the `response.body` was empty -- which, after checking if the body was empty as mentioned by Parag above, led to another occasional issue (`Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 5)`)

The `response.body` was empty because the PHP script was not echoing the result because it could not `json_encode` it. The reason this occurred is because it could not encode some characters in certain rows in the database.

The fix was as such in the PHP script:

```
// Connect to the MySQL database
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
// Set the charset to utf-8
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
```

This set the character set to "utf-8" and the data was able to be encoded and echoed after.