# FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 2) ^ in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a form with 6 fields. I am trying to send data to server after the button is pressed. But after pressing the button I got error: **FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 2) ^**. There are some number fields and some normal text fields. Do not understand why this error is occurring. Please help. Thanks in advance. Here is my dart code:

```
Future<SubmitData> userData(
  String uid,
  String saleAmount,
  String quantity,
  String rate,
  String brokerName,
  String partyName,
  String amountReceivable) async {
   Map<String, dynamic> map = {
   'uid': uid,
   'saleAmount': saleAmount,
   'quantity': quantity,
   'rate': rate,
   'brokerName': brokerName,
   'partyName': partyName,
   'amountReceivable': amountReceivable
 };

 final http.Response response = await http.post(
  'my php page',
   headers: <String, String>{
   'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
  body: jsonEncode(map),
 );

 if (response.statusCode == 201 || response.statusCode == 200) {
  return SubmitData.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
 } else {
  throw Exception('Failed to submit.');
 }
}

   class SubmitData {
    final String type;

    SubmitData({this.type});

    factory SubmitData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return SubmitData(type: json['type']);
  }
  }

  class UserForm extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
   return _UserForm();
  } 
 }

class _UserForm extends State<UserForm> {
 final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
 final uid = TextEditingController();
 final myController = TextEditingController();
 final myController2 = TextEditingController();
 final myController3 = TextEditingController();
 final myController4 = TextEditingController();
 final myController5 = TextEditingController();
 final myController6 = TextEditingController();

 @override
 void dispose() {
   // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
   uid.dispose();
   myController.dispose();
   myController2.dispose();
   myController3.dispose();
   myController4.dispose();
   myController5.dispose();
   myController6.dispose();
   super.dispose();
 }

 Future<SubmitData> _futureSubmitData;
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: (_futureSubmitData == null)
      ? Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Visibility(
              visible: false,
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: uid,
                initialValue: '1',
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: myController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
              decoration:
                  InputDecoration(hintText: 'Sale amount as per party'),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter amount.';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: myController2,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Item quantity'),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter quantity.';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: myController3,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Rate'),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter rate.';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: myController4,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Broker name'),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter broker name.';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: myController5,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Party name'),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter party name.';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: myController6,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Amount receivable as per party'),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter amount.';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.purple[400],
                textColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    setState(() {
                      _futureSubmitData = userData(
                          uid.text,
                          myController.text,
                          myController2.text,
                          myController3.text,
                          myController4.text,
                          myController5.text,
                          myController6.text);
                    });
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Submit', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      : FutureBuilder<SubmitData>(
          future: _futureSubmitData,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              if (snapshot.data.type == '1') {
                showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      content: Text('Data submitted successfully.'),
                    );
                  },
                );
                return Text('.');
              } else {
                showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      content: Text(
                          'Data not submitted. You have already submitted for today.'),
                    );
                  },
                );
                return Text('.');
              }
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
            }
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
        ),
     );
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54466639/json-decode-unexpected-end-of-input-at-character-1

Comment: Thanks for giving the reference. But in the reference the error was on json,decode. But in my case the problem occurs before sending data to server. Can you please suggest why the error is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for this. The value was not retrieved from

```
Visibility(
 visible: false,
 child: TextFormField(
  controller: uid,
  initialValue: '1'
 ),
)
```

So value of String uid was null and that's why the error occurred.

I had to remove initialValue: '1' and replaced

```
 final uid = TextEditingController();
```

with

```
 final uid = TextEditingController(text: "1");
```